# Botfront webchat widget not showing at Azure environment

Tags: azure, apache, chatbot

I'm running Rasa chatbot in container and apache2 in normal environment. When I open web page where chatbot is running there is no chatbot widget. When I run same configuration in my Virtual box environment, with *Ubuntu 18.04 desktop*, it works.

it only shows this, no error messages

```
// you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js
```

Some information below:

paulii@vetbot:~/rasaProd/rasaAsPa$ *sudo netstat -plnt*

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)  
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      839/systemd-resolve  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1073/sshd  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29130         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1423/mdsd  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1073/sshd  
tcp6       0      0 :::444                  :::*                    LISTEN      17464/apache2  
tcp6       0      0 :::5005                 :::*                    LISTEN      72983/docker-proxy
```

**index.html**
paulii@vetbot:~/rasaProd/rasaAsPa$ *cat index.html*

```
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="webchat"></div>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.min.js"></script>  
// you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js  
<script>  
  WebChat.default.init({
    selector: "#webchat",
    initPayload: "/aloitus",
    customData: {"language": "en"}, // arbitrary custom data. Stay minimal as this will be added to the socket
    socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
    socketPath: "/socket.io/",
    title: "Demo bot",
    subtitle: "Subtitle",
    params: {"storage": "session"} // can be set to "local"  or "session". details in storage section.
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**sites-availale conf**
paulii@vetbot:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cat 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:444>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ServerName aspabotti1.omnia.fi
        ServerAlias www.aspabotti1.omnia.fi
        # DocumentRoot /home/linttu/rasaProd/rasaAsPa
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Rasa docker running**
paulii@vetbot:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ *docker ps -a*

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES  
133db8a49155        rasa/rasa:1.10.11-full   "rasa run -m models …"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp   rasa2
```

**Ubuntu environment**
paulii@vetbot:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ *lsb_release -a*

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS  
Release:        18.04  
Codename:       bionic
```

**Docker version**
paulii@vetbot:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ *docker -v*

```
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
```

**Apache2 version**
paulii@vetbot:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ *apache2 -v*

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)  
Server built:   2020-08-12T21:33:25
```

**New testing 23.9.2020**
I tested with javascript code below and that works. So why starting javascript started remotely doesn't work?
This doesn't work

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.min.js"></script>
```

This works

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- hide this script from old browsers
function temp(form)
{
  var f = parseFloat(form.DegF.value, 10);
  var c = 0;
  c = (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
  form.DegC.value = c;
}
// done hiding from old browsers -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<FORM>
<h2>Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter</h2>
Enter a temperature in degrees F: 
<INPUT NAME="DegF" VALUE="0" MAXLENGTH="15" SIZE=15>
<p>
Click this button to calculate the temperature 
in degrees C:
<INPUT NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE=BUTTON 
onClick=temp(this.form)>
<p>
Temperature in degrees C is: 
<INPUT NAME="DegC" READONLY SIZE=15>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try and put the code lines inside the code block by editing your question. right now its hard to read.

Comment: much better. now, you just wait for the community to help you out. my focus was to welcome you to the community and help you make better questions.