# "http:/localhost:5005/socket.io/?&transport=polling&t=" error(s) on Chrome debug console window

Tags: javascript, apache, docker, socket.io

I have below shown index.html running in apache2 web server in Azure Ubuntu 18.04 server. It should start a chatbot widget on this http://aspabotti1.omnia.fi:444/ website, but the chatbot widget is not showing there.

When I look Chrome browser developer console I can see this error coming all the time, like currently 699 errors and counting

> http:/localhost:5005/socket.io/?&transport=polling&t=

Exactly same configuration works in my VirtualBox virtual linux environment, only difference is that is running in Ubuntu desktop environment

I have looked multiple similar issues pages, but still haven't found solution
What logs should I look?
What checking commands I should try?
What dummies I should try to isolate issue?

**index.html**

```
paulii@vetbot:/var/www/html$ cat index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="webchat"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.min.js"></script>
// poro you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js
<script>
  WebChat.default.init({
    selector: "#webchat",
    initPayload: "/aloitus",
    customData: {"language": "en"}, // arbitrary custom data. Stay minimal as this will be added to the socket
    socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
    socketPath: "/socket.io/",
    embedded: true,
    title: "Demo bot",
    subtitle: "Subtitle",
    params: {"storage": "session"} // can be set to "local"  or "session". details in storage section.
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are active internet connections

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29130         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1541/mdsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      858/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1191/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5005                 :::*                    LISTEN      102848/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1191/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::444                  :::*                    LISTEN      105455/apache2
```

This is full error message

```
index.min.js:129 Error: xhr poll error
    at u.i.onError (index.min.js:23)
    at l.<anonymous> (index.min.js:127)
    at l.r.emit (index.min.js:5)
    at l.onError (index.min.js:127)
    at index.min.js:127
index.min.js:127 GET http://aspabotti1.omnia.fi:444/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJ4tXI1 404 (Not Found)
```

This is my previous posting where you see full environment configuration and versions
[Botfront webchat widget not showing at Azure environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960043/botfront-webchat-widget-not-showing-at-azure-environment)

Comment: "http://localhost:5005" points to your loca computer, not the webserver. change this to match your apache webserver.

Comment: Like this?
    customData: {"language": "en"}, // arbitrary custom data. Stay minimal as this will be added to the socket  
    //socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",  
    socketUrl: "http://aspabotti1.omnia.fi:444",  

Still chatbot widget not working and same error on debug console, only the www adress changed to aspabotti1.omnia.fi i.e. "http:/aspabotti1.omnia.fi.444/socket.io/?&transport=polling&t="

Comment: changed back to 5005 local but now error message is different  

"index.min.js:127 GET http://localhost:5005/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJ5YlpT net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED."